# Matrix multiplication alglib

Tags: c#, alglib

How do I multiply two matrices with [AlgLib](http://www.alglib.net)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't used AlgLib; I'm just going by what the documentation seems to say. I'd be happy to be corrected by someone more expert.

Anyway, I'm afraid the answer seems to be that you need to use `cmatrixgemm` or `rmatrixgemm` (which one depends on whether your matrices are real or complex), like this:

```
rmatrixgemm(m,n,k, 1, A,0,0,0, B,0,0,0, 0, C,0,0);
```

where:

- `m`,`n`,`k` are the sizes of the matrices (`A` is `m` by `k`, `B` is `k` by `n`, `C` is `m` by `n`)
- the `1` is what to multiply the product by (if you happen to want, say, 3AB instead of AB, put `3` there instead)
- the `A,0,0,0` and `B,0,0,0` groups are: matrix, row offset, column offset, operation type

  - the operation type is 0 to use A or B as it is, 1 to use the transpose, and 2 to use the conjugate transpose (of course you can't use 2 for `rmatrixgemm`)
- the next `0` says to add 0*C to the result (if you put 0 here then the initial values in C are completely ignored)
- the two `0`s after C are a row and column offset

You might perhaps think that that level of generality is overkill, and that there should be a simpler function that provides those defaults. I wouldn't disagree with that, but so far as I can see there's no such simpler function in AlgLib. You might want to write your own (which would just call `rmatrixgemm` or `cmatrixgemm`).

(Why so much generality? Because doing an efficient matrix multiplication requires quite sophisticated code, and it's essentially the same quite sophisticated code as you need to do the more general `C=a.f(A).g(B)+b.C` operation that `*matrixgemm` does, and sometimes that more general operation is useful.)

EDITED to add a few more remarks that might be useful.

- The offsets are so that you can do things with submatrices. Being able to do this is useful in some numerical algorithms. I assume `m`,`n`,`k` are the sizes of the submatrices you're using; in the common case, they'll be the same as the dimensions of your arrays, and the offsets will be zero.
- The arrays themselves need to exist and be of appropriate sizes before you call `rmatrixgemm` or `cmatrixgemm`. At least, `A` and `B` certainly do; `C` is passed as a `ref` so it's possible that these functions will create it if it's `null` on entry.
- You might think from the signature of `rmatrixgemm` or `cmatrixgemm` that `A` and `B` get copied whereas `C` is passed by reference, but if I'm not totally confused about C#'s semantics they're all effectively passed by (object) reference.

Comment: wow... there was no way I could have figured that out by reading the manual ... thanks

Comment: For a less general, simpler function, it's always possible to create a function which uses `rmatrixgemm` internally with hard-coded dummy arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Just to confirm what Garech wrote:

```
double[,] a = new double[,] {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
};
double[,] b = new double[,] {
    {7,8,9,10},
    {11,12,13,14},
    {15,16,17,18}
};
int m = a.GetLength(0);
int n = b.GetLength(1);
int k = a.GetLength(1);
double[,] c = new double[m,n];
alglib.rmatrixgemm(m, n, k, 1, a, 0,0,0, b,0,0,0, 0, ref c, 0,0);
//c = {{74, 80, 86, 92}, {173, 188, 203, 218}}
```

Comment: Should the input matrices not be of type `alglib::integer_2d_array`?

Answer (score 0):

In vba I was able to use the complex version of this function.

```
Alpha.x = 1: Alpha.y = 0
Beta.x = 0:  Beta.y = 0

Call CMatrixGEMM(4, 1, 4, Alpha, r, 0, 0, 0, x, 0, 0, 0, Beta, RX, 0, 0)
```

as a side note the entire set of alglib functions can be loaded into any access program by loading all of the alglib modules into one access database and then setting a reference to that database from the current database where the functions are needed. This makes it very convenient and lightweight to the working database.

Comment: This library is also available for vb6 here: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=74940&lngWId=1