# How to add matrices with alglib?

Tags: c++, matrix, alglib

I already know how to multiply two matrices with alglib, using `rmatrixgemm` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607631/matrix-multiplication-alglib)).

Is there a way to compute a linear combination of two matrices without using this function, setting `B` to the identity ? It wouldn't be very efficient.

Alglib provides tons of complex algorithms but I can't find such a basic function.

The manual is [here](http://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why don't you try using another library that was created for the purpose of matrix math such as MTL4?

http://www.simunova.com/en/node/24

Manual - http://www.simunova.com/node/148

Comment: Indeed it seems that alglib isn't suited to this use.

Comment: This is useful info (pointing to similar libraries), but it should go in a comment under the question, not as a separate answer (because it doesn't actually answer the question).

Answer (score 0):

I think `rmatrixgencopy` is ALGLIB's way of providing matrix addition when you set the `alpha` and `beta` input parameters both to 1.

[`rmatrixgencopy` (C++)](https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.cpp.html#sub_rmatrixgencopy)

[`rmatrixgencopy` (C#)](https://www.alglib.net/translator/man/manual.csharp.html#sub_rmatrixgencopy)

Answer (score -1):

you might be able just to use alglib.cmatrixgemm to do Addition.

This subroutine calculates C = alpha*op1(A)*op2(B) +beta*C where:

- C is MxN general matrix
- op1(A) is MxK matrix
- op2(B) is KxN matrix
- "op" may be identity transformation, transposition, conjugate transposition.

If you want to do C = A + C, you just need to set: B = Identity, alpha = 1, beta = 1, op = identity transformation.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a benefit over doing it with `rmatrixgemm` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Not much, you can not add matrix that is not square. Have you tried MathNet.Numerics? it looks much simpler, just do: Matrix<double> A, Matrix<double> B, then print A + B.

Comment: I haven't done a benchmark, but I think it's probably not a great idea (for readability or performance) to use the ALGLIB multiplication routines in a degenerate configuration to do what 3 LoCs (probably a bit more if you use SIMD) could do.